# Variable within double quotes

Tags: php, variables, syntax

Which is the correct syntax?

```
$current_renewal_date = $wpdb->get_results(
                    "
                    SELECT expiry_date
                    FROM bid_tag
                    WHERE id = $renewal_tag_id
                    LIMIT 1
                    "
                );
```

OR

```
$current_renewal_date = $wpdb->get_results(
                    "
                    SELECT expiry_date
                    FROM bid_tag
                    WHERE id = {$renewal_tag_id}
                    LIMIT 1
                    "
                );
```

Comment: The first one. The second one might even work actually.

Comment: The second one is easier to read and handier when you need to refer to, say, `$renewal_tag_id['some_index']`. However, in this context, you should consider `$wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT .. WHERE id = %s LIMIT 1", $renewal_tag_id))` to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: SQL injection with a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @dcolumbus SQL injection does not mean ‘inject data into the database’ but ‘inject commands into the SQL statement’.

Comment: I edited my answer with some extra information that might be useful to you. Please keep it mind when you work with interpolated variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. The latter is just used to avoid ambiguity like if you want to reference `$foo` and not `$foobar`:

```
"{$foo}bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

They're both correct* and equivalent. When you’re just interpolating a variable and not accessing an element in an array, the braces are optional.

<sub>* Use parametrized queries please</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you could really say that there is a single correct form to put a variable within a string, but the most flexible and sure to work would be:

```
$current_renewal_date = $wpdb->get_results(
                    "
                    SELECT expiry_date
                    FROM bid_tag
                    WHERE id = ".$renewal_tag_id."
                    LIMIT 1
                    "
                );
```

There are at least 2 benefits of using this syntax instead of just putting the variable within the string.

**Variable misinterpretation**

1) When you put the variable within the string, you will probably experience problems if you need to mix the variable with other text.

Example:

```
$string = "My ID is AB$variableCD";
```

what is the variable? is it $variable? is it $variableC? or $variableCD? There are many interpretations for this on the syntax that you are using. This doesn't happen when you do

```
$string = "My ID is AB".$variable."CD";
```

**Array usage**

2) You can't easily use variables that have array indexes when you mix them within a string

Example:

```
$string = "The largest country is $options[countries in the world][$index]";
```

will get you *PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ']'*

while using the following will work perfectly:

```
$string = "The largest country is ".$options['countries in the world'][$index];
```

**And a little extra that isn't really a matter of syntax...**

3) And there is actually a performance benefit, and that is the possibility of using ' instead of " for your strings. Using ' makes the string literal, that is, it isn't parsed and this causes a performance improvement when handling large strings.

```
$string = 'hello';
```

instead of

```
$string = "hello";
```

Comment: why would that be any more correct than the ones in the question?

Comment: What do you mean, the most "sure to work"? They all work. String interpolation isn’t some kind of random process.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to explain: This is  because you avoid 2 big problems: 1) you avoid cases of character escape. 2) you avoid problems with name concatenation. I will modify my answer to add some examples and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Edited my answer, that should answer your questions. Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

They both *work*. The preferred way would be using prepared statements and bound parameters.