# Why login details in the database still declared invalid by the script when I try to login?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I downloaded the script from http://freestudentprojects.com on online banking. Everything seems to work except that the login pages keep saying my password and username are invalid.

None of the passwords and the loginid combinations in the SQL database is able to log me into the admin page (named: emplogin.php) Please help me know what's wrong. Is it mismatch of variables and values between the code and the database?

```
//emplogin.php page begins. Database is at the end of the php script.

<?php
session_start();
include("header.php");
include("dbconnection.php");
if(isset($_SESSION["employeeid"]))
{
    header("Location: employeeaccount.php");
}
if(isset($_SESSION["adminid"]))
{
    header("Location: admindashboard.php");
}

if(isset($_POST["loginadmin"]))
{
        //coding for login the employee account
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees
    WHERE loginid='$_POST[adminlogin]' AND password='$_POST[adminpass]'");


    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION["adminid"] =$_POST["adminlogin"];
        header("Location: admindashboard.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $logininfo = "Invalid Username or password entered";
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["loginemp"]))
{
        //coding for login the employee account
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees
    WHERE loginid='$_POST[emplogin]' AND password='$_POST[emppassword]'");


    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION["employeeid"] =$_POST["emplogin"];
        header("Location: employeeaccount.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $logininfo1 = "Invalid Username or password entered";
    }
}
?>
<div id="templatemo_main">
<p class="welcome_text">&quot;<strong>Administrator and Employee Login page.</strong>&quot;</p>

        <div class="col_w420 float_l">
     <div></div>
          <h2>Administrator Login page</h2>
          <div>
            <form id="form2" name="form1" method="post" action="">
              <p>
                <label for="adminlogin" class="leftal"><strong>Loginid</strong></label>
                <input name="adminlogin" type="text" id="adminlogin" size="40"  class="rightal"/>
              </p>
              <p class="cleaner_h50" id="password2">
                <label for="adminpass"  class="leftal"><strong>password</strong></label>
                <input name="adminpass" type="password" id="adminpass" class="rightal" size="40" />
              </p>
              <p class="cleaner_h50">&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000"><b><?php echo $logininfo; ?></b></font></p>
              <p class="cleaner_h50">
                <input  name="loginadmin" type="submit"   class="submit_btn float_r" id="loginadmin" value="Click here to Login"  />
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
<h2>Employee Login page</h2>
<div>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>
      <label for="emplogin" class="leftal"><strong>Loginid</strong></label>
      <input name="emplogin" type="text" id="emplogin" size="40"  class="rightal"/>
    </p>
    <p class="cleaner_h50" id="password">
      <label for="emppassword"  class="leftal"><strong>password</strong></label>
      <input name="emppassword" type="password" id="emppassword" class="rightal" size="40" />
  </p>
    <p class="cleaner_h50">&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000"><b><?php echo $logininfo1; ?></b></font></p>
    <p class="cleaner_h50">
     <input  name="loginemp" type="submit"   class="submit_btn float_r" id="loginemp" value="Click here to Login"  />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="button float_r"></div>

</div>
        <div class="cleaner"></div>
    </div> <!-- end of main -->
<div id="templatemo_main_bottom"></div> <!-- end of main -->
    <?php
    include("footer.php");
    ?>

//emplogin.php page ends
```

Below is the database for the script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `empid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `loginid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `emailid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `contactno` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `createdat` date NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=313800 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `employees`
--
INSERT INTO `employees` (`empid`, `employee_name`, `loginid`, `password`, `emailid`, `contactno`, `createdat`, `last_login`) VALUES
(313786, 'soudhabanu', '445545', '125487', 'soudha_ban@52yahoo.com', '9535543313', '2012-12-15', '2012-12-03 11:27:00'),
(313787, 'mahesh', 'mahesh', 'qwert', 'mahesh@gmail.com', '98478872783', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(313788, 'jyothi', '3535355', '3636', 'jyothi@yahoo.com', '95425422424', '2013-01-02', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(313791, 'admin', 'admin', 'admin', 'admin', 'admin', '2013-01-12', '2013-01-12 00:00:00'),
(313798, 'raj', 'rajkiran', '123456', 'abc@gmail.com', '9874563210', '2013-02-02', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(313799, 'peter king', 'emp', 'emp', 'emp@gmail.com', '987456321', '2013-02-09', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Comment: This script will have your server hacked quickly, as it has SQL injection vulnerabilities in it, and it does not properly hash the password. Please don't use it, and (assuming this code is from the source you've cited) it would be good if you could alert the owner of that site to this page, so they can see my comments.

Comment: does only the admin-login not work or do neither of the logins work?

Comment: Also, the Location redirect is not followed by an exit(). (I earlier suggested the indexes were not properly quoted, but I believe this OK when they are inside double-quote strings.)

Comment: @northkildonan, Neither the admin-login nor any other login works

Answer (score 3):

The following code:

```
"SELECT * FROM employees 
 WHERE loginid='$_POST[adminlogin]' AND password='$_POST[adminpass]'"
```

is incorrect

The issue is related to string concactenation, you can build the string this way:

```
$sql= sprintf("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE loginid ='%s' AND password='%s'",
                mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adminlogin']),
                mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adminpass']));
```

Using `mysql_real_escape_string` to avoid sql injection, and if you get a chance you should update to mysqli using prepared statements.

Comment: no, that's not the problem, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060063/variable-within-double-quotes). you escaped the strings, what is fine, but it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @northkildonan he is right, `'$_POST` will not be interpolated.

Comment: @OZ_ sorry, my bad. didn't know that since i always concatenate strings by myself.

Comment: +1 This answer shows a viable pattern. (String concatenation would also work; the big rocks addressed in this answer are the addition of single quotes in `$POST['adminlogin']`, and the use of  `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Wut. Simple array varexpressions [work quite fine in double quoted string context](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple), regardless of preceding single quotes.

Comment: @media, thanks but I did replace this code
"SELECT * FROM employees 
 WHERE loginid='$_POST[adminlogin]' AND password='$_POST[adminpass]'"

with the correction you gave:
$sql= sprintf("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE loginid ='%s' AND password='%s'",
                mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adminlogin']),
                mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adminpass']));
It still did not work. Something else, I should have done? Neither the admin login nor the other logins work

Comment: @mario yeah but using `$_POST` variables doesn't as it seems. i tried it.

Comment: @northkildonan looks like is my bad :) I was wrong. Thanks mario.

Comment: @OZ_ what? i am really confused now.

Comment: @ElizabethKof I recommend you to `print mysql_num_rows($result)` and also the query. you should make sure your connection to mysql is successful and that you can manually run the query in the server directly

Comment: @meda          Thanks for your help but I am confused here. I don't know how to get the code to work. Please can you edit the entire code with your corrections? This would really help me and I would very much appreciate this.

Comment: @ElizabethKof okay, what is the issue now, the redirect is not working or do you get the error `Invalid Username or password entered`

Comment: @meda yeah I get the error invalid username or password

Comment: @ElizabethKof why do you run 2 select, if you get data from the same table ? this will be an issue for admin because you have `SELECT * FROM employees` there

Comment: @meda Running 2 select is the method I could use but it's not working which is why I need help. I would like know how to deal with the problem but at the moment I am confused about the suggestions so far.

Answer (score 0):

`if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)` is returning false, there are few possibility:

- Your connection is not even successful
- `mysql_query` is returning false so therefore `mysql_num_rows` is failing
- You are not getting any results, returns 0 records

Here are few ways, to do it:

Using `mysql_num_rows`

```
if(isset($_POST["loginemp"]))
{
    $sql= sprintf("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE loginid ='%s' AND password='%s'",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emplogin']),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emppassword']));

    //coding for login the employee account
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo 'sql = '.$sql;
    echo 'mysql_num_rows() = ' .mysql_num_rows($result);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION["employeeid"] =$_POST["emplogin"];
        header("Location: employeeaccount.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $logininfo = "Invalid Username or password entered";
    }
}
```

Using `mysql_fetch_row`

```
if(isset($_POST["loginemp"]))
{
    $sql= sprintf("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE loginid ='%s' AND password='%s'",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emplogin']),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emppassword']));

    //coding for login the employee account
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo 'sql = '.$sql;

    if (mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $_SESSION["employeeid"] =$_POST["emplogin"];
        header("Location: employeeaccount.php");
    } else {
        $logininfo = "Invalid Username or password entered";
    }

}
```

I added more code to display the sql that you should be testing, and also the result count.

If you get more issues, you can use `COUNT(*)`, and check the value returned.

You struggled with this piece of code for few days now, you have to learn some basic php debugging because PHP is not very sophisticated for helping you find the issue.

Always attempt to print, log, values etc ...